# Impossible to insert data with PyMySQL when I use parameter

Tags: python, python-3.x, insert, pymysql

I'm currently working on a basic query which insert data depending on the input parameters, and I'm unable to perfom it.

`cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo (bar1, bar2) values (?, ?)", (foo1, foo2))`

I have this error message:

> Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "/usr/lib/python3.2/tkinter/**init**.py", line 1426, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)   File "test.py", line 9, in register
>       cur.execute("INSERT INTO foo (bar1, bar2) values (?,?)", (foo1, foo2))   File
>   "/usr/local/lib/python3.2/dist-packages/pymysql/cursors.py", line 108,
>   in execute
>       query = query % escaped_args TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'bytes' and 'tuple'

foo1 and foo2 are both string type. I tried with `%s`, same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like a [`bug`](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/pull/143) in `cursors.py`. As suggested [here](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/issues/109) and [here](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/issues/83) you should replace this line in `cursors.py`:

```
query = query % conn.escape(args)
```

With this:

```
query = query.decode(charset) % conn.escape(args)
```

In case it didn't work try this one instead:

```
query = query.decode(charset) % escaped_args
```

Comment: I didn't find this line `query = query % conn.escape(args)` in my cursors.py, so I tried to modify this line `query = query % escaped_args` (related to this [post](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/issues/83)) by your line. But now I have this: "TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting"

Comment: Thanks a lot! It works with `query = query.decode(charset) % escaped_args` and by using `%s` instead of `?`. :D